# UX Best Practices for web based map

Tags: web, maps

I am looking for best UX practices for controlling a map in a web environment.
The use cases I'm looking for are:

1. Creating/editing shapes and polygons
2. Switching maps
3. Playing with object layers

Whenever I'm searching for map UX in google the search results are related to mapping UX process in a project and no to real maps.

Any examples of web based map controls are welcome (well, except for google maps :)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Your question is rather broad as it is. You'll probably get more feedback if you limit the scope, e.g. concentrate on one of the use cases, or present one or two design drafts with specific questions. Help us helping you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you didn't search with appropriate keywords. Here are a few useful webpages of what you are looking for:

[Best practices for designing map applications](http://www.designingmapinterfaces.com/patterns/)

[UI Concept And User Experience Design Of Google Maps](http://www.uianduxdesign.com/ux-designs/ui-concept-and-user-experience-design-of-google-maps.html)

[Bye, Google Maps.](https://medium.com/@zmh/bye-google-maps-ea3ea10f84dc#.g7lr4gh0g)

Answer (score 0):

The following link will help you to edit **Gmap**, manipulate and adjust **UX**. Let's try it.

[Snazzy Maps](https://snazzymaps.com/)
[image]

Comment: How does this answer the question ?